# multiple image store kinect with different name

Tags: c++, opencv, save

I want to know how to change the default save folder to store differents images with differents names

If i do like this it only store one image, 
//capture from camera

```
while(1)
{
sprint(buffer, "/folder", i++);
}
```

and like this it store correctly but in a different folder

```
while(1)
{
sprint(buffer, "%d", i++);
}
```

how to combine them?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using the following code:

```
char fileName[500];
sprintf(fileName,"./folderyouwanttosaveto/nameofimage%u.png",i++);
imwrite(fileName, imageToSave);
```